# Mysql order by: to skip zeros to end of list

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, zero

```
$query = "SELECT products.*, login1.* 
          FROM products LEFT JOIN login1
               ON products.id_user = login1.id_user
          WHERE products.product LIKE '".$search_keyword."'
          ORDER BY products.product, products.rate "
```

When using this query the products with rate 0 list first, But I want that to display last, with no other change in the order. How can I achieve this.

Comment: `ORDER BY *** DESC` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: i want the ASC order except for ZERO

Comment: You need an if statement.

Comment: I rolled back edit #2 as the `*` character is being recognise as formatting character when using `>` to do a citation and therefore won't get printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "
  SELECT products.*, login1.*
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN login1 ON products.id_user = login1.id_user
  WHERE products.product LIKE '" . $search_keyword . "'
  ORDER BY IF(products.rate = 0, 1, 0), products.product, products.rate "
```

This adds an initial check to the sort order so that products with a rate of `0` are listed after all products that have a rate not equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT products.*, login1.* 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN login1 ON products.id_user = login1.id_user 
WHERE products.product LIKE '".$search_keyword."' 
ORDER BY products.product, products.rate = 0,products.rate
```

It will first order by whether or not rate is 0. If it is 0 then this will get the value 1 and be placed at the end. The other values will then order by rate as usual.

Comment: Won't this order by `products.product` first before `products.rate` is taken into account?

Comment: @Aiias Yes, this was how the order was in the original so I wanted to retain that.